# Filtering adjacent values and applying function on them

Tags: java

I have list of numbers, for example 1, 5, 10, 15. Assuming these are links and current input is 1, then I would only be able to see 5, which is "next" value. When the input is 5, I would be able to see value 1, which represents "previous" and 10, which is "next". I only care about next and previous, and not anything past these or the input itself. Array is always ordered and has no duplicates.

I am looking a nice way to find out what these next and previous values are from an integer array, and then call a function on one or both values, depending if it has 2 adjacent values or just one, if it's the first or last element.

I've been trying to achieve something nice and fluent using Java 8 lambdas, but ended up with not very clean code.

Anyone can advice something on this?

Comment: It's an array. It can be accessed by an index. [KISS](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using streams in this case is not appropriate. Use binary search on an already sorted array to find the index of your element, then invoke the consumer on the previous and next index if they exist in the array:

```
<E> void invokeOnPreviousAndNext(E[] array, E element, Consumer<E> consumer) {
    int index = Arrays.binarySearch(array, element);
    if (index > 0) {
        consumer.accept(array[index - 1]);
    } 
    if (index >= 0 && index < array.length - 1) {
        consumer.accept(array[index + 1]);
    }
}
```

So the following code:

```
Integer[] array = { 1, 5, 10, 15 };
invokeOnPreviousAndNext(array, 1, s -> System.out.printf("%s ", s));
System.out.println("//");
invokeOnPreviousAndNext(array, 5, s -> System.out.printf("%s ", s));
System.out.println("//");
invokeOnPreviousAndNext(array, 10, s -> System.out.printf("%s ", s));
System.out.println("//");
invokeOnPreviousAndNext(array, 15, s -> System.out.printf("%s ", s));
System.out.println("//");
invokeOnPreviousAndNext(array, 0, s -> System.out.printf("%s ", s));
System.out.println("//");
```

would output the following:

```
5 //
1 10 //
5 15 //
10 //
//
```

Note that it works correctly even if the element is not found in the array.

Comment: Like the comment on the question said, KISS. I don't see how this is better than my answer.

Comment: Did you even ran your code, at least mentally? It's bugged. My code checks for possible corner cases and uses lambdas as the question requested.

Comment: The question doesn't ask for lambdas, it just says they already tried them. Thanks, I fixed my code.

Comment: Not trying to be picky here, but -1 is not the only answer `Arrays.binarySearch` can give if the element is not found in the array. Check the [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch-java.lang.Object:A-java.lang.Object-).

Comment: Oops, thank you very much. We have practically identical answers now :P

Comment: Streams was too much. Consumer is good, it makes it readable and that is what I need. I don't need speed, so binary search or not, what looks the most clean and understandable.

Answer (score 0):

```
int index = java.util.Arrays.binarySearch(theArray, input);
if (index > -1) {                      // if input was found
  if (index - 1 > 0)                     // if previous isn't the first item
    execute(theArray[index - 1]);          // run operation on previous
  if (index + 1 < theArray.length - 1)   // if next isn't the last item
    execute(theArray[index + 1]);          // run operation on next
}
```

Comment: Binary search is used here because the array is already sorted and there are no duplicates. It is also incredibly fast.

Comment: Update: check that index isn't -1 from not being found. And fixed it so that it doesn't break when the item found IS the first or last item.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [`java.util.Arrays`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) to convert your array to a list via `Arrays.asList(array)` to create methods that return the next and previous entry like this (assuming no duplicates and that the list is already in order, as the question says):

```
public int getPrevious(int[] array, int entry){
    try {
        return array[Arrays.asList(array).indexOf(entry) - 1];
    } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        //if code gets here, this means that the entry passed is the first entry
    }
}

public int getNext(int[] array, int entry){
    try {
        return array[Arrays.asList(array).indexOf(entry) + 1];
    } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        //if code gets here, this means that the entry passed is the last entry
    }
}
```

Comment: This is pretty awful solution.

Comment: This solution is perfect for if the array isn't sorted. But otherwise, it could be faster with a binary search instead.

Comment: As mentioned it is sorted and the speed is not important. The list will hold maximum 10 values and I am not chasing nanoseconds here. Catching out of bounds exceptions is far for being clean code and is just terrible practice.

Comment: "Clean" code is pretty pointless compared to easily readable.